# Date Search conversion issues

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to run a very simple search on a scaffolded index view. Normally this works for me but using dates I am not able to get it to work.

The code in my controller is:

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime SearchDate)
{
    var query = from a in db.AppointmentProcedures
                where a.BookingStatus == false
                orderby a.AppointmentStartTime
                select a;

    if (SearchDate != null)
    {

         query = from a in db.AppointmentProcedures
                    orderby a.AppointmentDate
                    where a.AppointmentDate == SearchDate
                    select a;
    }

    return View(query);
}
```

However I am getting conversion issues. On the view I just have a simple date time picker.

Comment: What's the **actual error?**

Comment: A DateTime can not be null.  What is possibly happening is that SearchDate == DateTime.MinValue and there is no SQL DateTime representation for that value.

Comment: @drch that makes sense, assuming a datetime always comes back, what would be a way to query dates on that day (as I assume == will assume time aswell)

Comment: The actual error message would be helpful to solve your issue faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime is a struct and can not be null.  If MVC can't bind it, it will use `default(DateTime)` which is equal to `DateTime.MinValue`.

DateTime.MinValue is January 1, 0001 but a Sql DateTime has a minimum value of January 1, 1753.  If you try to use DateTime.MinValue in a query, it will give you an error.

To fix this you can use a Nullable DateTime.  The change in your code would look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? SearchDate)
{
    var query = ...;

    if (SearchDate != null)
    {
         query = ...;
    }

    return View(query);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your `AppointmentDate` type is date?

If yes,  there is no need to convert `SearchDate` to `string`

Comment: Sorry, AppointmentDate is a DateTime. I forgot to change that code before posting. Please see updated solution

Answer (score 1):

If it **can** be `null`. Or in other words, the user **didn't** specify a value **and** the control allows `null`. Then you want your parameter to look like this:

```
DateTime? SearchDate
```

That will allow you to do this:

```
if (SearchDate.HasValue)
```

and further change your query to this:

```
query = from a in db.AppointmentProcedures
        orderby a.AppointmentDate
        where a.AppointmentDate == SearchDate.Value
        select a;
```

If it **can't** be `null`. Then yes, check for the `MinValue`:

```
if (SearchDate != DateTime.MinValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It is quite weird that you store date as a string in the database
2. Make a conversion before like:

```
var converted = Convert.ToString(SearchDate);
query = from a in db.AppointmentProcedures
orderby a.AppointmentDate
where a.AppointmentDate == converted
select a;
```

because it will not recognise the Convert.ToString() function (will try to interpret as a SQL function).